# Linq fill function

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a Linq operator that will ensure that a collection is a minimum size

What I would like to see is:

```
int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4};
var y = x.Fill(6);

// y is now {1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0}
```

Note (from the answers so far) I'm looking for something that will work with `IEnumerable<T>`.  `int[]` was just for easy initialization in the example

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, but an extension method wouldn't be hard:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> PadRight<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int length)
{
    int i = 0;
    // use "Take" in case "length" is smaller than the source's length.
    foreach(var item in source.Take(length)) 
    {
       yield return item;
       i++;
    }
    for( ; i < length; i++)
        yield return default(T);
}
```

Usage:

```
int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4};
var y = x.PadRight(6);

// y is now {1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0}

y = x.PadRight(3);

// y is now {1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.  I'll accept it as soon as SO lets me (there is a minimum time before an answer can be accepted)

Comment: If this is mirroring the `PadRight` for strings, `.Take(length)` shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 4):

No, but you can combine `Concat`, `Repeat` and `Take` to achieve this.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> PadRight<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int length) =>
    source.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(default(T), length)).Take(length);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in Linq that would do that in a single call - also note that because linq is for *querying* not *modifying*, any such method wouldn't change your collection anyway (but might return an extended version of your collection).

That said, an extension method like this would return such a result:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Fill<T>(this IEnumerable<T> target, int minLength)
{
    int i = 0;

    foreach (var item in target)
    {
        i++;
        yield return item;
    }

    while (i < minLength)
    {
        i++;
        yield return default(T);
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the OP is looking to mutate the collection?  His question makes it very clear that he's not mutating it through the use of multiple variables.

Comment: I disagree: the question doesn't make clear what happens to the original collection (certainly it doesn't make clear whether he's looking to mutate the original since the result of his call is assigned to a different variable), so I highlighted that a Linq method would *not* mutate the original, and gave sample code to that effect. I can only guess that my assumption was correct since functionally my code is the same as the accepted answer (minute the `.Take`).

Answer (score 0):

```
            int minLength = 6;
            var x = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            x.Select(i => { minLength--; return i; }).Concat(
                Enumerable.Repeat(0, minLength).TakeWhile(i => minLength-- > 0));
```

Comment: This will throw an exception if the sequence is longer than the pad length.  it also requires knowing the size of the sequence, which isn't possible for any arbitrary `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Fair point, just trying to do the IEnumerable thing without having to add a subroutine! (Slightly horrible) edit should fix this :)

Comment: `count` is going to be evaluated to `0` every time in the second query as it is executed before the first query has been able to increment it at all.

Comment: yes, you're right - I'm determined to get this working though... new edit!

Comment: That now works, but its using very poor design practices (you're mutating the same variable from multiple different LINQ queries in which the order of execution is not at all obvious) and is just a mess to read.  It's far inferior as a solution from creating a very simple and straightforward iterator block that reads very much like the spec for the method should.

Comment: I do realise that. It's a shame Zip() doesn't have an option to continue to the end of the longer sequence, which would be perfect for this use case.